# Interactive svg from data uri in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, react-dom

I want to cache my svgs externally on cdn, so is there a way to import them from cdn and use them as react components. I've tried embedding them in object tag, but unable to manipulate the css, is there a way to manipulate the css when embedding svgs in object tag in React.

Comment: SVG in a data URI is not interactive by design. What you want is therefore impossible.

Comment: @RobertLongson so there is no possible way to move the svgs outside of the application and still keep them interactive.

Comment: sure there is, you can put them in <iframe> tags or <object> tags.

Comment: I've done that, but how to edit the styling then

Comment: @RobertLongson svg isn't interactive when I embedded it in object tag, I'm unable to edit the styling using css

Comment: Inject the styling via javascript or put the styling in the file itself.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm not able to inject the styling in react, I can access the elements of svg, like in javascript we could do document.getElement, can you please tell how do I inject the style using react( placing styling in svg file is not an option)

Comment: get the object or iframe's document and write the style element in via that.

Comment: I tried using reference to access the object element, can't directly access document in react.

Comment: @RobertLongson and when using reference to get the <object>, unable to select the svg as childNode, can you please tell in a bit detail, how to do this in react, thanks

Comment: document.getElementById("whatever the id of the object element is").documentElement